# A contestant on a game show wins five dollars for each correct answer. The game is played as follows:...

Tags: probability

A contestant on a game show wins five dollars for each correct answer. The game is played as follows: the contestant is allowed to continue answering questions until giving an incorrect answer at which time the game ends. If the probability a given contestant gives an incorrect answer is 1/3. What is the expected dollar winnings? Assume each question is independent of prior questions.

Thanks for reading the entire question!

Here's what I've done but I'm not sure if this is correct:

Let X = dollar winnings of each answer
E(X) = ($5)(2/3) + ($0)(1/3) = (10/3).

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution?wprov=sfti1) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculated the expected value of winning during the first round.  However, $2/3$ of the time the contestant wins the first round and gets to play again, thus repeating the initial scenario.  Hence,

$$E(X) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot 5 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 0 + \frac{2}{3}E(X)$$

which you can solve for $E(X)$.

Comment: Aaah I get it. So it should be $$E(X) = 10?$$ Nice explanation btw.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  As a check:  The expected winnings in the first round are $\frac{2}{3} \cdot 5$.  The expected winnings in the second round are $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \cdot 5$.  In general, the expected winnings in the $k$th round are $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k \cdot 5$.  Hence, the expected winnings are $$E(X) = 5 \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = \frac{10}{3} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k - 1} = \frac{10}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2}{3}} = 10$$